# ''str' object does not support item assignment' python 2

Tags: python-2.7

So this is my code it is strying tomease car registration plates, start times and end times (In the complete code it would be printed at the bottom).

```
data = str(list)
sdata = str(list)
edata = str(list)
current = 0
repeats = input ('How many cars do you want to measure?')

def main():
    global current
    print (current)
    print ''
    print ''
    print '---------------------------------------'
    print '---------------------------------------'
    print 'Enter the registration number.'
    data[current] = raw_input('    ')
    print 'Enter the time it passed Camera 1. In this form HH:MM:SS'
    sdata[current]   = raw_input('    ')
    print 'Enter the time it passed Camera 2. In this form HH:MM:SS'
    edata[current]   = raw_input ('    ')
    print '---------------------------------------'
    print''
    print''
    print''
    print 'The Registration Number is :'
    print data[current]
    print''
    print 'The Start Time Is:'
    print sdata[current]
    print''
    print 'The End Time Is:'
    print edata[current]
    print''
    print''
    raw_input('Press enter to confirm.')
    print'---------------------------------------'
    d = d + 1
    s = s + 1
    a = a + 1
    current  = current = 1

while current < repeats:
    main()
```

When I run it and it gets to:

```
data[current] = raw_input('    ')
```

I get the error message 'TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment'
Thank you in advance for the help. :D

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear. `str object does not support item assignment`

Strings in python are immutable. You have converted the data to a string when you do

```
data = str(list)
```

So, by

```
data["current"] = raw_input()
```

you are trying to assign some value to a string, which is not supported in  python.

If you want data to be a list,

```
data = list()
```

or

```
data = []
```

will help, thus preventing the error

Answer (score 0):

Dont use str during assignment

```
data = str(list)
sdata = str(list)
edata = str(list)
```

Instead use

```
data = []
sdata = []
edata = []
```

and later while printing use str if u want

```
print str(data[current])
```

as aswin said its immutable so dont complex it